# Galeria con carousel dinámico en laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-blade, bootstrap-carousel

Tengo en funcionamiento una galería dinámica, donde voy a recoger los datos a mi base de datos (lo cual me funciona), pero no se como mostrar una cierta cantidad de fotos y que pase automáticamente al otro slider,

Mi intención era hacer dentro del `foreach` un ciclo `for`, pero no me resulto y arrojaba error. Implementé con `->chunk()` y sí me dio resultado. No sé si es la manera correcta de aplicar lo que quiero. Mi código es el siguiente:

En mi controlador tengo este código:

```
$foto=Img::where("if", "=", $user->id)->get();
```

Mi blade es el siguiente

```
<div class=" carousel-item">
    @if($foto->count()>0)
        @foreach($foto->chunk(4) as $imagen)
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($imagen as $img)
                    <div class="col-md-3 d-md-inline-block">
                        <img class="panel-img img-fluid" src="{{$img->id}}">
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Actualmente si tengo 20 imagenes, me muestra las 20 imagenes de 4 columnas.  Pero me gustaria que me mostrara solo 8 imagenes en columnas de 4 y pasara al siguiente slider.

En la siguiente imagen muestro como me gustaría que se viera, por si no me supe explicar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué le falta a mi código para mostrar como lo necesito?
Gracias

Comment: porque no utilizas `take` y tomas las ocho primeras imagenes y despues validas con `$loop->iteration == 8` y muestras el siguiente carrousel

Comment: Cando dices "pasara al siguiente slider" es un mismo carrousel u otro slider?

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias por la orientación, pero soy nuevo en laravel y no me manejo al 100%, pero intento hacer lo mejor posible, cuando me hablas de take, eso debo agregarlo en funcion del controlador? y el loop va después del foreach o estoy equivocado?

Comment: en tu primer foreach deberia ir el `take(8)` lo que hace es tomar los primeros 8 elementos,  `$loop->iteration ` itera sobre los elementos restantes, en lo  que hago unas pruebas para responderte puedes apoyarte en la documentacion https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: Grcias amigo por la ayuda

Comment: lograste resolverlo?

Comment: Dohko 19, si ya lo pude implementar a mis necesidades, muchas gracais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia `$foto->chunk(4)` por `$foto->chunk(8)` e incluye este div: `<div class=" carousel-item">` dentro del primer `@foreach` y tendrás 8 imágenes dentro de cada item del carousel.

```
@foreach($foto->chunk(8) as $imagen)
    <div class="carousel-item @if($loop->first) active @endif">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($imagen as $img)
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img class="panel-img img-fluid" src="{{$img->id}}">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!! Me salvaste